# Flink job hangs on submission when loading big file

Tags: java, csv, timeout, jobs, apache-flink

I wrote a Flink streaming job in Java that loads a csv file that contains subscriber data (4 columns) and then reads data from a socket stream while matching against the subscriber data.

Initially I was using a small csv file (8 MB) and everything was working fine:

```
# flink run analytics-flink.jar 19001 /root/minisubs.csv /root/output.csv
loaded 200000 subscribers from csv file
11/02/2015 16:36:59 Job execution switched to status RUNNING.
11/02/2015 16:36:59 Socket Stream -> Flat Map -> Filter -> Map -> Stream Sink(1/1) switched to SCHEDULED 
11/02/2015 16:36:59 Socket Stream -> Flat Map -> Filter -> Map -> Stream Sink(1/1) switched to DEPLOYING 
11/02/2015 16:36:59 Socket Stream -> Flat Map -> Filter -> Map -> Stream Sink(1/1) switched to RUNNING
```

I switched the csv file to a bigger one (~45 MB) and now all I see is this:

```
# flink run analytics-flink.jar 19001 /root/subs.csv /root/output.csv
loaded 1173547 subscribers from csv file
```

Note that the number of subscribers above is the number of lines in the file. I tried to look for any timeouts in the Flink configuration but I couldn't find any.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Edit: Csv is loaded using this method by utilizing the commons-csv 1.2 library:

```
private static HashMap<String, String> loadSubscriberGroups(
            String referenceDataFile) throws IOException {
        HashMap<String,String> subscriberGroups = new HashMap<String, String>();

        File csvData = new File(referenceDataFile);
        CSVParser parser = CSVParser.parse(csvData, Charset.defaultCharset(), CSVFormat.EXCEL);
        for (CSVRecord csvRecord : parser) {
            String imsi = csvRecord.get(0);
            String groupStr = csvRecord.get(3);

            if(groupStr == null || groupStr.isEmpty()) {
                continue;
            }
            subscriberGroups.put(imsi, groupStr);
        }

        return subscriberGroups;
    }
```

and here's a sample of the file (I know there's a comma at the end, the last column is empty for now):

```
450000000000001,450000000001,7752,Tier-2,
450000000000002,450000000002,1112,Tier-1,
450000000000003,450000000003,6058,Tier-2,
```

Comment: How exactly to do load the CSV file? Can you provide a snippet of your program that reads the CSV file?

Comment: post edited to add csv loading method

Comment: Thanks for the update. What are doing with the CSV data? How do you inject it into the Flink program?

Comment: CSV data is loaded into memory and referenced later from within the 'map' operators I'm using in the Flink program.

Comment: So what is your data source? Why do you not read CSV as `env.readFile(FileInputFormat<OUT> inputFormat, String filePath)`?

Comment: My data source is a socket. The CSV file is just used for reference data when processing data from the socket. I could try the suggested code but I'm pretty sure I'd run into the same problem. Flink doesn't register the job if it takes too long to set up.

Answer (score 4):

From Robert Meztger (apache flink developer):

> I can explain why your first approach didn't work:
>
> You were trying to send the CSV files from the Flink client to the
>   cluster using our RPC system (Akka). When you submit a job to Flink,
>   we serialize all the objects the user created (mappers, sources, ...)
>   and send it to the cluster. There is a method
>   StreamExecutionEnvironment.fromElements(..) which allows users to
>   serialize a few objects along with the job submission. But the amount
>   of data you can transfer like this is limited by the Akka frame size.
>   In our case I think the default is 10 megabytes. After that, Akka will
>   probably just drop or reject the deployment message.

The solution would be to use a rich operator instead of a regular operator (e.g. RichMapFunction instead of MapFunction), overriding the open() method and loading the CSV file inside that method.

Thanks Robert!